# About ethical sleeping in Islamic philosophy

Tags: ethics, islamic-philosophy

In Islamic philosophy, those who die are divided into those who die in sleep and those who do not die in sleep. The following link is the relevant question: [Sleep and Death](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/22676/sleep-and-death)

The truth is that if a person is sleep-deprived, it is a mortal who dies. Sleep is a state of unbusyness that reorganizes the brain's working order.

In another possibility, if a person is sleep-deprived, he gets as far away as possible from the causes that lead it to death ([Az-Zumar 42](https://quran.com/39/42)). If this is true, then there must be reasons that do not put people to sleep. Is there a threshold for human tolerance for these assumptions, or are people unable to distinguish between sleep and death because they are frightened by death? After all, it is not possible to predict exactly when death will come. Can the person who does not die without sleeping be proof, or is it just fallacy?

Of course, Islam, like some religions, contains extraordinary descriptions. However, if it is not possible to encounter such an extraordinary phenomenon on behalf of *our species*, given the human condition, does this mean that it may be necessary to torture people in order to isolate them from sleep at the expense of killing? Or what were people overlooking in this status?

Why do Muslims discount a person's metabolic state as a trump card to others when they wake up close to sunrise and have a very limited sleep time? Is it for everytime?

While Islamophobia is on the rise, if the negation of the Qur'an is not enough to prevent vandalism, how ethical is it? I think there will be no problem here as long as we deal with this issue openly and without being sharp-tongued.

Comment: You may have more luck with this question on [islam.se]. Although I'm having difficulty making sense of what you're asking. Scientifically speaking, there's no difference functional between dying in your sleep or dying while awake, and there are lots of differences between sleeping and being dead. Although sleeping and being dead are similar in the sense that both involve an absence of conscious experience (with the exception of dreams, arguably). In this day and age, it doesn't seem all that rational to fear sleep for its relation to death (not that fear is commonly rational).

Comment: Since we live according to the metaphor, there is a possibility that we will die in sleep. We don't know who will die and how, but a person's life can be an omen of how they will die. This needs to be taken into account so that kamikaze attacks are not carried out... I'm still reaching dysfunctional and unpeaceful conclusions.